# How can I mock the files property in ServiceStack's IHttpRequest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack

I upload files via a HTTP Post and get the files from the Request.Files property. OK - now I want to test my service.

The code of my service:

```
    public void Post(MyFileRequest request)
    {
        var files = base.Request.Files;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            url = this.uploader.UploadFile(Session, file);
        }
    }
```

For mocking the request I'm using the MockRequestContext as follows:

```
    private MyService CreateMyService(Session session)
    {
        var myService = new MyService(this.uploaderMock.Object)
        {
            RequestContext = GetRequestContextMock(session)
        };

        return myService;
    }

    private IRequestContext GetRequestContextMock(Session session)
    {
        var mockedRequestContext = new MockRequestContext();
        mockedRequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().Items.Add(ServiceExtensions.RequestItemsSessionKey, session);
        return mockedRequestContext;
    }
```

Is there a chance to mock the Files property in IHttpRequest?